# Python. Как "нарисовать" степень числа, используя функцию print

Tags: python

Как нарисовать степень числа при выводе числа на экран?

Например,

```
a = 4
print('a = ', 2, '^2')
```

Как вместо галочки поставить степенной регистр?

Comment: @Эникейщик Поддерживает )  Ну, смотря какая ОС, конечно, ещё

Comment: @CrazyElf винда не умеет. В линукс переключаться сейчас не буду :) upd. И точно линукс умеет!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Немного дополню ответ Danis'a, правда только для целочисленных значений и немного уродски выглядит в консоли )))

```
indexes = {"0": "\u2070",
           "1": "\u00B9",
           "2": "\u00B2",
           "3": "\u00B3",
           "4": "\u2074",
           "5": "\u2075",
           "6": "\u2076",
           "7": "\u2077",
           "8": "\u2078",
           "9": "\u2079",
           "-": "\u207B"
           }


def degree(a: int):
    degrees = ""
    temp = str(a)
    for char in temp:
        degrees += indexes[char] or ""
    return "a = " + temp + degrees


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(degree(1024))
    print(degree(-1024))
    print(degree(int(input("Введите число: "))))
```

Вывод:

```
a = 1024¹⁰²⁴
a = -1024⁻¹⁰²⁴
Введите число: -659897
a = -659897⁻⁶⁵⁹⁸⁹⁷
```

**UPDATE**

Ну и немного подправил, чтобы юзабельно было (может кому и пригодится):

```
def degree(digit: int, deg: int):
    degrees = ""
    temp = str(deg)
    for char in temp:
        degrees += indexes[char] or ""
    return "a = " + str(digit) + degrees


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(degree(1024, 56))
    a, b = map(int, input("Введите число и степень: ").split())
    print(degree(a, b))
```

Вывод:

```
a = 1024⁵⁶
Введите число и степень: 23 5698
a = 23⁵⁶⁹⁸
```

Answer (score 7):

Вот так, но универсального решения нет, это для конкретно степени `2` символ UTF-8:

```
a = 4
print('a = 2\u00B2')
```

Вывод:

```
a = 2²
```

[Ссылка на таблицы кодов для степеней](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts)

[Ссылка на таблицы кодов для остальных математических символов](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_operators_and_symbols_in_Unicode)

Comment: блин, как-то по-уродски в IDLE выглядит, да еще и не отличишь одно от другого :(

Comment: Спасибо! То, что надо!

Comment: Вроде [норм](https://imgur.com/yYBWQvV.png) выглядит

Answer (score 5):

Есть таблица символов юникода, оттуда можно брать.

Можно скопировать отсюда:
https://unicode-table.com/ru/sets/superscript-and-subscript-numbers/

Comment: и как это применить используя функцию print()?

Answer (score 4):

```
dict_ = {
    0: "\u2070",
    1: "\u00B9",
    2: "\u00B2",
    3: "\u00B3",
    4: "\u2074",
    5: "\u2075",
    6: "\u2076",
    7: "\u2077",
    8: "\u2078",
    9: "\u2079"
}

a = 4
print("a = ", str(a) + dict_[2])
```

Comment: `print("a = ", str(a) + dict_[a])` - чтобы не было ненужного пробела между числом и степенью )